# How do you show multiple function calls to the same class?

Tags: uml, communication-diagram

For my deposit use case in the communication diagram below: I make 3 successive calls to the `Account` class which contains `isPreferred()`, `isCardHolder()`, and `updateBalance()`. I don't know if the looping symbol I used above `Account` is a way to display multiple calls to the same class, so any help is appreciated.

[image]

My operation sequence:

[image]

The possible sequence scenario I'm aiming for:
1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 (printReceipt).

Comment: where are the name of the called operations in the diagram ?

Comment: >I make 3 successive calls to the Account class which contains isPreferred(), isCardHolder(), and updateBalance().

aren't operations left out of the communication diagram?

Comment: ok but where is visible in your diagram ? Even the numbering is wrong because it does not correspond to the messages

Comment: how is the numbering wrong? i don't know if it should be visible in the diagram: my professor leaves operations out of the diagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your diagram does not show the messages nor their numbering, the numbering you show correspond to nothing

out of that your reflexive arrow is correct having self message(s)

an extract of the sequence following normalized notation can be :

[image]

it is also possible to use hierarchical numbering rather than global numering

P.S. classes *Screen/DBinterface* and message *communicate_DB* are very 'strange' but this is not the subject of the question

Comment: oh i see now; i wish i could do this, but my professor doesn't want operations to be in the diagram

Comment: @S.Coughing if operations do not appear the diagram is fully useless, are you sure you understand your professor ? Note it is also possible to use hierarchic numberig for the message

Comment: i understand my professor: his examples did not include operations on the diagram . . .

Comment: @S.Coughing What on earth do you want if the above is not the answer/being allowed?

Comment: @qwerty_so i want to know if there is a way to show multiple function calls to my Account class in the communication diagram i included in the question

Comment: @S.Coughing from where the numbers 1,2,3,3,3,4,... come, statement ?can you use other numbers in the diagram ? if no there is not even illegal way to show what you want

Comment: i don't understand what your asking me, but that's the path my diagram follows if it's a successful deposit

Comment: I want to say if the 3 reflexive message are all numbered 3 it is not possible to distinguish them not to know there are 3, but if you can use/show different numbers in the diagram for them at least we know there are 3 .... even this is stupid because not showing the message we learn nothing in fact. I really think you understand wrong your teacher

Comment: @S.Coughing What Bruno shows in the answer is a real [communication diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/communication-diagrams.html). Communications require a sequence numbering AND a message (which takes the name of an operation).  If your professor doesn't want it, he/she doesn't teach UML.

Comment: alright thanks guys, and i agree that DBinterface/communicate_DB are very strange; i'm closely following my professor's example. this might not be a correct communication diagram, but it is close? just that the sequence number and message are split into two different separate images or slides since my professor is using powerpoint.

Comment: @S.Coughing Screen is also very strange

Comment: @bruno i can include my class diagram in my original message; the screen class is just used to display the atm's gui?

Comment: @S.Coughing Screen cannot be a class. Yes you can edit your question to give more information ... except if you want to ask a different question

Comment: @S.Coughing why you added the class diagram ? if you want we speak about it this is an other question ... and must be given in an other question (with not only the diagram but a question to explain;-) )

Comment: @bruno got it sorry, i don't know how i would phrase that question